# Javascript select onchange submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

this is my site (wordpress site):
http://orbix.hedgehogworks.net/?page_id=924

I have a form next to the text "Filter By Location:". I want to have the form submitted, when one of the selected options were selected (onChange).

I have tryed this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $('#oflocations').change(function()
 {
     $('.searchandfilter').submit();
 });
</script>
```

and this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#oflocations').change(
    function(){
         $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    });
</script>
```

But none of these way works.

Comment: are you doing this in a dom ready state?

Comment: is the script tag before or after the select element?

Comment: after. you can see in the code of the site.

Comment: we prefer that the relevant code is on this site, not linked to.

Comment: ok i will know for next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the DOM is ready for attaching events, manipulation, etc..

That's why there's the `$(document).ready()` function (read more [here)](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). To make sure everything (relevant, not images or ad banners for instance) is ready before you try to change/select/attach events:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#oflocations').on('change', function()
     {
         $('.searchandfilter').submit();
     });
 });
</script>
```

**EDIT**: Changed from `.change` to `.on('change', ..`

**EDIT 2**: According to the error of `undefined` for the `$(document)`, it looks like you have not loaded JQuery correctly. Make sure it's loaded in your page.

Comment: i have tryed using this code but it dosn't do nothing. ותודה על העזרה.

Comment: yes. it says: "$(document).ready(function () {"   =  "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)"

Comment: @user3003106 You haven't loaded JQuery then. You need to include it. Updated the answer.

Comment: o yes ! it is a wordpress site. what was needed to do is to wrap the code you gave with: jQuery(function($){ // your code here });

Answer (score 1):

Do in `$(document).ready(function ()` Because DOM should be ready first.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#oflocations').change(function()
     {
         $('.searchandfilter').submit();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

DOM must be ready first to trigger the event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#oflocations').change(function()
     {
         $('.searchandfilter').submit();
     });
 });
```